# How to create a table of custom shapes in iced (Rust GUI framework)?

Tags: rust, rust-iced

I'm trying to create a GUI for a board game engine. To that end I'm trying to transform the State (A struct with a grid where game pieces can be) into a rendered grid.
I decided to try and do this with Iced, but I'm having trouble getting a custom shape into the grid structures in Iced. I should add that I'm pretty new to rust in general, and so my problems might not be with understanding Iced specifically.

I tried a few approaches, mainly these:

1. Implement the custom widget trait for the octagon, based on the `custom_widget` example from the Iced repository. I did not keep the code I used for this attempt, but at some point I realized (I think) that Iced has two classes of widgets, built-in and custom, where the custom ones do not promise full widget behavior and the built-in ones are harder to implement.
2. Try to encapsulate the struct in a Canvas widget, and implement `canvas::Program<Message>` with my own `draw` function.

Both of these resulted in a similar compilation error, when writing the view function for my implementation of Application:

```
fn view(&self) -> iced::Element<'_, Self::Message> {
    let matrix = self.get_board();
    let mut base = Column::new().padding(20).spacing(20);
    for row in matrix {
        let mut gui_row = Row::new().padding(20).spacing(20);
        for value in row {
            // ...get details about the specific piece in 
            //    this cell
            let oct = crate::gui::octagon::Octagon::new(30.);
            // this is the line I want to change, and push a custom
            // struct with an octagonal shape instead of a button
            gui_row = gui_row.push(Button::new("Pushing a button works"));
        }
        base = base.push(gui_row);
    }
    base.into()
}
```

Where I get the following:

```
the trait bound `iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'_, (), iced_renderer::Renderer<Theme>>: From<Column<'_, Message>>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
  <iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'a, Message, Renderer> as From<Column<'a, Message, Renderer>>>
  <iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'a, Message, Renderer> as From<MouseArea<'a, Message, Renderer>>>
  <iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'a, Message, Renderer> as From<Row<'a, Message, Renderer>>>
  <iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'a, Message, Renderer> as From<iced::widget::Button<'a, Message, Renderer>>>
  <iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'a, Message, Renderer> as From<iced::widget::Checkbox<'a, Message, Renderer>>>
  <iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'a, Message, Renderer> as From<ComboBox<'a, T, Message, Renderer>>>
  <iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'a, Message, Renderer> as From<iced::widget::Container<'a, Message, Renderer>>>
  <iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'a, Message, Renderer> as From<menu::List<'a, T, Message, Renderer>>>
and 15 others
required for `Column<'_, Message>` to implement `Into<iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element<'_, (), iced_renderer::Renderer<Theme>>>`
```

A minimal(ish) reproduceable example:

```
use iced::widget::{Canvas, Column, Row, Button};
use iced::{executor, Color, Application, Command, Settings, Theme};


#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Piece; // some sort of Octagon

struct State {
    board: [[Option<Piece>; 4]; 4]
}

impl Application for State {
    type Executor = executor::Default;
    type Flags = ();
    type Message = ();
    type Theme = Theme;

    fn new(_flags: ()) -> (State, Command<Self::Message>) {
        (State {board: [[None; 4]; 4]}, Command::none())
    }

    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("A cool application")
    }

    fn update(&mut self, _message: Self::Message) -> Command<Self::Message> {
        Command::none()
    }

    fn view(&self) -> iced::Element<'_, Self::Message> {
        let matrix = self.board;
        let mut base = Column::new().padding(20).spacing(20);
        for row in matrix {
            let mut gui_row = Row::new().padding(20).spacing(20);
            for value in row {
                let color = match value {
                    Some(piece) => Color::BLACK,
                    None => Color::WHITE,
                };
                let oct = crate::octagon::Octagon::new(30.);
                gui_row = gui_row.push(Canvas::new(oct));
            }
            base = base.push(gui_row);
        }
        base.into()
    }
}

pub fn main() -> iced::Result {
    State::run(Settings::default())
}

mod octagon {
    use iced::{Rectangle, mouse, Renderer, Theme, Point, widget};
    use iced::widget::{canvas, container};
    use iced::widget::canvas::{Event, event, Cache, Path};

    pub enum Message {
        None
    }

    pub struct Octagon {
        size: f32,
        cache: Cache
    }

    impl Octagon {
        pub fn new(size: f32) -> Octagon{
            Octagon {size: size, cache: Cache::new()}
        }
    }

    impl canvas::Program<Message> for Octagon {
        type State = ();

        fn update(
            &self,
            _state: &mut Self::State,
            event: Event,
            bounds: Rectangle,
            cursor: mouse::Cursor,
        ) -> (event::Status, Option<Message>) {
            todo!()
        }

        fn draw(
            &self,
            _state: &Self::State,
            renderer: &Renderer,
            _theme: &Theme,
            bounds: Rectangle,
            _cursor: mouse::Cursor,
        ) -> Vec<canvas::Geometry> {
            let geom = self.cache.draw(renderer, bounds.size(), |frame| {
                // this is not an octagon, but it's some sort 
                // of geometric shape that I can't render
                frame.stroke(            
                    &Path::new(|builder| {
                        builder.line_to(Point { x: 0., y: 0. });
                        builder.line_to(Point { x: 206., y: 131. });
                        builder.line_to(Point { x: 9., y: 699. });
                        builder.close();
                    }),
                    canvas::Stroke::default(),
                );
            });

            vec![geom]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close already.

1. The `Message` enum must be exported (so that it can be used as an [Associated Type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) in the `Application` implmentation) and implement `Debug` (it must implement `Debug`, because of [this](https://docs.rs/iced/0.10.0/iced/application/trait.Application.html#associatedtype.Message) trait bound):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub(crate) enum Message {
    None,
}
```

2. Use the `Message` enum from the `octagon` module in your `Application` implementation:
   `type Message = octagon::Message;`
3. This is not needed for compilation but otherwise the program will `panic` at runtime. Change the `update` function of the `canvas::Program<Message>` implementation, to for example:

```rust
fn update(
    &self,
    _state: &mut Self::State,
    event: Event,
    bounds: Rectangle,
    cursor: mouse::Cursor,
) -> (Status, Option<Message>) {
    (Status::Ignored, None)
}
```

Here is the full fixed sample:

```rust
use iced::widget::{Canvas, Column, Row};
use iced::{executor, Application, Color, Command, Settings, Theme};

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Piece; // some sort of Octagon

struct State {
    board: [[Option<Piece>; 4]; 4],
}

impl Application for State {
    type Executor = executor::Default;
    type Flags = ();
    type Message = octagon::Message;
    type Theme = Theme;

    fn new(_flags: ()) -> (State, Command<Self::Message>) {
        (
            State {
                board: [[None; 4]; 4],
            },
            Command::none(),
        )
    }

    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("A cool application")
    }

    fn update(&mut self, _message: Self::Message) -> Command<Self::Message> {
        Command::none()
    }

    fn view(&self) -> iced::Element<Self::Message> {
        let matrix = self.board;
        let mut base = Column::new().padding(20).spacing(20);
        for row in matrix {
            let mut gui_row = Row::new().padding(20).spacing(20);
            for value in row {
                let color = match value {
                    Some(piece) => Color::BLACK,
                    None => Color::WHITE,
                };
                let oct = crate::octagon::Octagon::new(30.);
                gui_row = gui_row.push(Canvas::new(oct));
            }
            base = base.push(gui_row);
        }
        base.into()
    }
}

pub fn main() -> iced::Result {
    State::run(Settings::default())
}

mod octagon {
    use iced::event::Status;
    use iced::widget::canvas;
    use iced::widget::canvas::{Cache, Event, Path};
    use iced::{mouse, Point, Rectangle, Renderer, Theme};

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub(crate) enum Message {
        None,
    }

    pub struct Octagon {
        size: f32,
        cache: Cache,
    }

    impl Octagon {
        pub fn new(size: f32) -> Octagon {
            Octagon {
                size: size,
                cache: Cache::new(),
            }
        }
    }

    impl canvas::Program<Message> for Octagon {
        type State = ();

        fn update(
            &self,
            _state: &mut Self::State,
            event: Event,
            bounds: Rectangle,
            cursor: mouse::Cursor,
        ) -> (Status, Option<Message>) {
            (Status::Ignored, None)
        }

        fn draw(
            &self,
            _state: &Self::State,
            renderer: &Renderer,
            _theme: &Theme,
            bounds: Rectangle,
            _cursor: mouse::Cursor,
        ) -> Vec<canvas::Geometry> {
            let geom = self.cache.draw(renderer, bounds.size(), |frame| {
                // this is not an octagon, but it's some sort
                // of geometric shape that I can't render
                frame.stroke(
                    &Path::new(|builder| {
                        builder.line_to(Point { x: 0., y: 0. });
                        builder.line_to(Point { x: 206., y: 131. });
                        builder.line_to(Point { x: 9., y: 699. });
                        builder.close();
                    }),
                    canvas::Stroke::default(),
                );
            });

            vec![geom]
        }
    }
}
```

Giving you this output:
[image: Iced Canvas Screenshot]

If you want to render actual octagons you can change the `draw` function to:

```rust
fn draw(
    &self,
    _state: &Self::State,
    renderer: &Renderer,
    _theme: &Theme,
    bounds: Rectangle,
    _cursor: mouse::Cursor,
) -> Vec<canvas::Geometry> {
    let geom = self.cache.draw(renderer, bounds.size(), |frame| {
        frame.stroke(
            &Path::new(|builder| {
                let r = 50.;
                for i in 0..8 {
                    let angle_rad = 360. / 8. * i as f32 * std::f32::consts::PI / 180.;
                    builder.line_to(Point {
                        x: angle_rad.cos() * r + r,
                        y: angle_rad.sin() * r + r,
                    });
                }

                builder.close();
            }),
            canvas::Stroke::default(),
        );
    });

    vec![geom]
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the help!
Can I ask you to explain the compilation error in the answer? As in:
    a. It makes sense to me that in order to push an item into a row/column that Item would need to be an Element<something, ... > but the error message implies that the column itself should be cast?
    b. I don't quite understand why adding a global message and deriving debug are necessary. I'm also not quite sure I completely understand what changing the return type did (except lose some complexity, I guess), I tried both options and got the same results.

Comment: Also, for some reason my application seems to only be able to render the first entry in the grid (the first pushed canvas). I'm assuming this is some sort of machine dependent problem but if you (or anyone else) have some insight I'd love to hear.

Comment: I added some more context and removed the step of adjusting the function definition as it is not neccessary (but it still would be cleaner to change it to `iced::Element<Self::Message>` in my opinion).
Regarding the compile error, I think you do misinterpret it. Basically the compiler tells you that it can not perform the cast using `.into()`, because several trait bounds are not satisfied for your current canvas to be casted to a  `iced::advanced::iced_graphics::iced_core::Element`.

Comment: I can't say much towards the last part. It works just fine for me on MacOS and Windows, so I guess this could be a bug in `iced`.